# Embed a Business Facebook page in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, android-webview

I would like to embed a business Facebook page on my application. I tried to find information, but there's nothing. I don't know if I should use the SDK or graph API and how I should use it. I found a post here some years ago, but no one answered. Can you please help, at least give me some directions?

Thanks!

**SOLUTION**:

It uses the webview with `setWebViewClient`, otherwise, it redirects to the browser. But the important thing I was missing is that the Facebook page has to be PUBLIC.

Comment: Specify “embed” – do you want to show the page’s latest post, information about the page, maybe its profile or cover picture – _what_?

Comment: @CBroe I want to display the whole page without having to login or redirect to the facebook app

Comment: Well then opening a WebView or something like that, with the URL of the page, would be the only easy option.

Comment: With the WebView It shows the login first, that's not what I want. I know that with the graph.facebook I can get some informations but not the whole page

Comment: You should be able to get most information (at least what’s public) – but you would have to assemble a view/layout out of those parts yourself.